# To read String text content after Converting HTMl to text in java

Tags: java, string, jsoup, html-email

I am having HTMl Form in email body, how can i read string text content after converting HTML FORM into text. Can Anyone please help me?

**Email Body - HTML Form:**
[image: OldImage]
[image: NewImage]

**Email Body - HTML Form Content:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
        {font-family:Helvetica;
        panose-1:2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
        {font-family:"Cambria Math";
        panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
        {font-family:Calibri;
        panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
        {font-family:"Century Gothic";
        panose-1:2 11 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
        {margin:0in;
        margin-bottom:.0001pt;
        font-size:11.0pt;
        font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
span.EmailStyle17
        {mso-style-type:personal-compose;}
.MsoChpDefault
        {mso-style-type:export-only;
        font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
        {size:8.5in 11.0in;
        margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
        {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal"><img width="809" height="364" style="width:8.427in;height:3.7916in" id="Picture_x0020_4" src="cid:image001.jpg@01D609B1.5BB77760"><o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">Non-Contacted/Non-Qualified Leads from Ateco:&nbsp; <o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1553" style="width:1165.0pt;margin-left:-.15pt;border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td width="167" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:125.0pt;border:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#4472C4;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Name<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="111" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:83.0pt;border-top:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;background
;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Mobile<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="259" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:194.0pt;border-top:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;backgroun
4;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Email<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="103" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:77.0pt;border-top:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;background
;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Postal Code<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="109" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:82.0pt;border-top:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;background
;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Enquiry Date<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="239" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:179.0pt;border-top:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;backgroun
4;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Lead Source<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="261" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:196.0pt;border-top:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;backgroun
4;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Dealer<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="93" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:70.0pt;border-top:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:
padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Date Sent
<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
<td width="212" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:159.0pt;border:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-left:none;background:#4472C4;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b><span style="color:white">Preferred Model<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td width="167" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:125.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:none;backgroun
2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">Test Justin<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="111" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:83.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;background:#D9E1F2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">&#43;61 420 888 999<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="259" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:194.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;background:#D9E1F2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">testmail@hotmail.com<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="103" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:77.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;background:#D9E1F2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">4218<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="109" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:82.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;background:#D9E1F2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">31-03-20<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="239" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:179.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;background:#D9E1F2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="261" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:196.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;background:#D9E1F2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">QLD - Von Bibra Gold Coast - 554216<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="93" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:70.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;background:#D9E1F2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">03-04-20<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
<td width="212" nowrap="" valign="bottom" style="width:159.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;border-right:solid #8EA9DB 1.0pt;backgroun
2;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:black">T60 4WD Diesel Dual Cab Ute<o:p></o:p></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">Thank you,<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">Anna<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span lang="EN-AU" style="color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">Anna Tupou</span></b><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-family:&quot;Helvetica&quot;,s
f;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-AU" style="color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">Call Centre Supervisor ÔÇô Lead Management</span><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-famil
Helvetica&quot;,sans-serif;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU"><br>
</span><b><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-family:&quot;Century Gothic&quot;,sans-serif;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU"><img width="294" height="34" style="width:3.06
ght:.3541in" id="_x0038_11B48E0-2644-4F0E-A8FF-F2DD7ECD462F" src="cid:image002.jpg@01D609B1.5BB77760" alt="cid:BD091752-D740-4B3A-B050-FF52A328E5C8"></span></b><b><span lan
" style="font-family:&quot;Century Gothic&quot;,sans-serif;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU"><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-AU" style="mso-fareast-language:EN-AU"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">2A Hill Rd Lidcombe NSW 2141 Australia</span><span lang="EN-AU" styl
size:10.5pt;color:#005CFB;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">
<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#005CFB;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">P</span><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:black;mso
-language:EN-AU"> ÔÇé&#43;61 2 8577 8097ÔÇé</span><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#005CFB;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">|</span><span lang="EN-AU" style="fon
0.5pt;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">ÔÇé</span><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#005CFB;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">
 E</span><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:black;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">ÔÇé</span><u><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:blue;mso-fareast-l
EN-AU">atupou@ateco.com.au<o:p></o:p></span></u></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#005CFB;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">M&nbsp;
</span><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:10.5pt;mso-fareast-language:EN-AU">0407 588 506<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:10.0pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<p><b><span style="font-size:13.5pt;font-family:webdings;color:green">P</span> <span style="font-size: 7.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:gree
<i>: Please consider the environment before printing this e-mail. </span></i></b></p>
<p id="disclaimer-input" style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; color: gray; font-size: 7.5pt;" class="txt">
IMPORTANT NOTICE: If this e-mail is received by other than the named addressee, please notify us immediately by telephone or return e-mail and delete all copies from your c
system. This document contains information proprietary to Ateco Group and its
 affiliates or third parties to which Ateco may have a legal obligation to protect such information from unauthorised disclosure, use or duplication. Any disclosure, use or
tion of this document or the information contained herein for other than the
 specific purpose for which it was disclosed by Ateco is expressly prohibited. It is the recipient's responsibility to check this message and attachments for viruses.
</p>
<div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<br>
<p>┬á</p>

<p align="center" style="text-align:center">**********Disclaimer**********</p>

<p style="text-align:justify">&quot;This email and any
attachments are confidential and are for the intended addressee[s] only.
Unauthorised use of this communication is prohibited. If you have received this
communication in error, please notify the sender and remove them from your
system. Confidentiality is not waived or lost by reason of the mistaken
delivery to you. Please scan this email and any attachment(s) for viruses. It
is your responsibility to check them before opening&quot; </p>

<p align="center" style="text-align:center">********End of
Disclaimer*********</p>
```

**String Content after convertion (Email Body):**

```
Non-Contacted/Non-Qualified Leads from Ateco:

Name
Mobile
Email
Postal Code
Enquiry Date
Lead Source
Dealer
Date Sent
Preferred Model
Test Justin
+61 420 888 999
testmail@hotmail.com
4218
31-03-20
LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive
QLD - Von Bibra Gold Coast - 554216
03-04-20
T60 4WD Diesel Dual Cab Ute

Thank you,
Anna


Anna Tupou
Call Centre Supervisor ÔÇô Lead Management


2A Hill Rd Lidcombe NSW 2141 Australia
P ÔÇé+61 2 8577 8097ÔÇé|ÔÇé EÔÇéatupou@ateco.com.au
M 0407 588 506


P : Please consider the environment before printing this e-mail.
IMPORTANT NOTICE: If this e-mail is received by other than the named addressee, please notify us immediately by telephone or return e-mail and delete all copies from your computer
system. This document contains information proprietary to Ateco Group and its affiliates or third parties to which Ateco may have a legal obligation to protect such information fro
m unauthorised disclosure, use or duplication. Any disclosure, use or duplication of this document or the information contained herein for other than the specific purpose for which
 it was disclosed by Ateco is expressly prohibited. It is the recipient's responsibility to check this message and attachments for viruses.


**********Disclaimer**********
"This email and any attachments are confidential and are for the intended addressee[s] only. Unauthorised use of this communication is prohibited. If you have received this communi
cation in error, please notify the sender and remove them from your system. Confidentiality is not waived or lost by reason of the mistaken delivery to you. Please scan this email
and any attachment(s) for viruses. It is your responsibility to check them before opening"
********End of Disclaimer*********
```

**Note**: I need to make exact key value pair for eg. **Postal Code : 4218** .

Comment: Pleas show the raw mail body. Preprocessing it will make it loose structure, so avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any DOM Parser library to parse your HTML. You can simply give id to any HTML tag and then you can get that element. I'll suggest you [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library.

Use below code using Jsoup library

**Add ID in HTML**

```
<p id="POSTAL_CODE">4218</p>
```

**Java Code**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

Element elPostalCode = doc.getElementById("POSTAL_CODE");
String postalCode = elPostalCode.text();
```

You can also use attribute extraction for your HTML, for more information about attribute extraction using Jsoup you can visit [this](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) page.

.
.

For more information, you can refer [this](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-html/) article, in this article they have mentioned multiple HTML parsing libraries for multiple programming languages.

**Code for your exact problem**

.

**NOTE:** This code will only work when you will be having exact same number of p tags in each row including the header.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, String>> dataPairs = new ArrayList<>();

Elements trElements = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");

    for (int i = 0; i < trElements.size(); i++) {
    Element element = trElements.get(i);
    Elements pElements = element.getElementsByTag("p");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < pElements.size(); i1++) {
        Element p = pElements.get(i1);
        if (i == 0) {
            keys.add(p.text());
        } else {
            map.put(keys.get(i1), p.text());
        }
    }
    dataPairs.add(map);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
Thanks for your idea. HTML FORM comes from Email Body(ie from client side), i can't able to give id for each and every key.

Comment: @Justin, In that case, you have to use attribute parsing or something else for extraction, you can explore some data extraction techniques mentioned here https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
Can you show me an example to extract at least one element by using above HTML Form data (ie refer "Email Body - HTML Form Content:" from my question? that would be great help for me.

Comment: Considering that you would get all your text data in <p> tag
**I did not test this code but it should work.**

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

        Elements pElements = doc.getElementsByTag("p");

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        for (Element p : pElements) {
            text.append( p.text());
            text.append("\n");
        }

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
the above jsoup parsing returns the same content which i shared in question(see: String Content after conversion (Email Body)). i am expecting the way to map key with exact value from above email content like i mentioned .( for eg. Postal Code : 4218,Name : test Justin etc ).

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
Can you please test your code? and let me know if you get exact key and values. i have checked. it shows all content like i mentioned above(see: String Content after convertion)

Comment: Hi Justin, your HTML format will be the same always, I mean, your data would be always in table format? If yes, then I can write a code that should be work and if the format will be changing every time and you would not get data in table form then your problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
As i mentioned in my question(see Email Body - HTML Form), datas are always comes by form only(table format only). may be one are two keys will be added more in the form, but form structure remains same. let me know if you have any other doubts. awating for your response. thanks in advance

Comment: Okay, great, I have updated my answer by adding the code which supposes to solve your exact problem. The code will only work when you will be having exact same number of <p> tag in each row including the header. And also I did not test the code so let me know if it will not work.

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
 I can't able to access my lap for the last day.Sorry for late reply. The given solution works fine if table header and no of  <p> tag is same as you said.

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
As i mentioned earlier, there is new table column with empty values came(See 2nd image in question), if i put values manually under that column, values not comes under <p> tag. may i know reason?

Comment: Hi @Nilesh,
if values are empty for some column,<p> tag not coming under <td>. So it will fetch next <p> tag values into previous column.can i know how to handle this?